# Vuejs / axios child component not passing through object

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I have the following components:

- Users
- Addresses

Inside the `Users` component I have the following:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() { 
    return {
      address: null 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Inside the view, I have the following (calling the child component)

```
<partials-addresses source="/users" title="Users Address" @addressChanged="address = $event" placement="address" />
```

This is then sent to an endpoint (using axios):

```
submitForm: function() {
    var vm = this; 

    console.log(vm.address); // is fine, returns the object 

    axios.post(`/users`, {
       address: vm.address 

    }); 

 }
```

The issue is that when I'm outputting the data on the endpoint side, I'm just getting an empty array. I'm using another child component and this sends data through fine, it's just the address one.

Could it be because of the way the data is formatted?

Comment: Your code looks okay. There is probably some issue with your backend.

Comment: Please provide more _code_. It's unclear where the problem is occurring.

Comment: If you are getting empty array - it is weird, as far as you are sending object from the code I can see. Mb error is in backend.

Comment: @yev Problem is not in the backend, sadly. It works if I do the following: 
`address: { postcode: vm.address.postcode, address_1: vm.address.address_1 }` this sends the data to the backend no problem